# How do I run a .class file created in a Mac on a windows?

Tags: java

I made a program in Java on my Macbook. It compiled and executed properly.
I took the .class file and tried to run it in an another machine with windows on it. 
I wanted to examine the platform independent feature of Java.
It first gave me Java launcher error and then kept saying, main class not found.
I did run the program on my **Mac** using the terminal with the following commands *javac file.java* 
and executed it with *java classname*
Took the class file and tried to run in a **windows machine** using the *command line with the command java classname.*
Things did not run then

Comment: share the code for your class, might be issues with the package name

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to help you. Specifically, what command did you use to run it on your Mac vs. the command you used to run it on your Windows machine?

Comment: What is the command line that you are using? Does the class have a main method? Does it run on the Mac?

Comment: The key there is probably not that you are running on windows. It's likely that you do not have a main class defined in your manifest. You have to have this or define the main class on the java command line. You probably ran it in an IDE on Mac.

Comment: @rmlan I did run the program on my mac using the terminal with the javac file.java and executed it with java classname Took the class file and tried to run in a windows machine using the command line with java classname. Things did not run then

Comment: First off, that doesn't really clear it up. Secondly, you should edit your question with the _exact_ commands you used on each platform. Do not comment again, edit the question.

Comment: @joshp I did not use an IDE on mac. Compiled and executed via the terminal. Tried the same with a windows machine using the command prompt.

Comment: @Tusharj You don't show what command you are running. You have not posted a minimal concrete example of your code that fails, or of the specific error message. So everyone is somewhat guessing here as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Has nothing to do with the OS, if java is installed on the windows machine, the class files should run. First make sure you have the JVM installed, if that's not it, it is because your are not running your main class.

Run main from cmd with this command.

java -cp "ClassPath" FileName